# Using Flutter Form Builder how to change the date value of FormBuilderDateTimePicker by adding the value of FormBuilderFieldOption

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

I am a newbie to flutter and i'm trying to change the initialValue of flutter FormBuilderDateTimePicker on click over the one of the chips, created with FormBuilderChoiceChip. I need to add the value of each FormBuilderFieldOption under the FormBuilderChoiceChip to the initialValue of FormBuilderDateTimePicker.
Here's the code:

```
 child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                 FormBuilderChoiceChip(
                   attribute: "custom_days",
                   spacing: 3.0,
                   options: [
                     FormBuilderFieldOption(
                       child: Text("3 Days"),
                              value: 3
                     ),
                     FormBuilderFieldOption(
                       child: Text("5 Days"),
                              value: 5
                     ),
                     FormBuilderFieldOption(
                       child: Text("7 Days"),
                              value: 7
                     ),
                   ],
                  ),
                  FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
                    attribute: "date",
                    inputType: InputType.date,
                    format: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Select Date"),
                    initialValue: DateTime.now(),
                  )
                 ]
                )
```

here is the image of the output:
[image]
on click over each chip, the value should be added to the initialvalue of the date and and get update to the future date.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the underlying value of the `date` attribute using the `onChanged` event but the initial value of the attribute remains the same on the UI.

```
FormBuilderChoiceChip(
              attribute: "custom_days",
              spacing: 3.0,
              onChanged: (daysToAdd) {
                _fbKey.currentState.save();
                _fbKey.currentState.setAttributeValue(
                    'date',
                    _fbKey.currentState.value['date']
                        .add(Duration(days: daysToAdd)));
                _fbKey.currentState.save();
              },
              options: [
                FormBuilderFieldOption(
                    child: Text(
                      "3 Days",
                    ),
                    value: 3),
                FormBuilderFieldOption(
                    child: Text(
                      "5 Days",
                    ),
                    value: 5),
                FormBuilderFieldOption(child: Text("7 Days"), value: 7),
              ],
            )
```

`setAttributeValue()` only works in the background but doesn't update the UI as explained [here](https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/issues/81#issuecomment-505292101) by the package creator.

Answer (score 0):

you can change field values by `didChange` or `patchValue`. on your chip onChnage update the date field.

change single field value using didChange :

```
_formKey.currentState.fields['color_picker'].didChange(Colors.black);
```

change multiple fields value using patchValue

```
_formKey.currentState.patchValue({
  'age': '50',
  'slider': 6.7,
  'filter_chip': ['Test 1'],
  'choice_chip': 'Test 2',
  'rate': 4,
  'chips_test': [
    Contact('Andrew', 'stock@man.com', 'https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX4057996.jpg'),
  ],
});
```

[please check the api reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_form_builder/latest/)